# MySQL: Is there a way to speed up a left join looking for rows that do not match a row in another table?

Tags: mysql, indexing, left-join

I have a query that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo
        LEFT JOIN bar
        ON bar.id = foo.bar_id
        WHERE bar.id IS NULL
        LIMIT 30;
```

It's attempting to find entries in `foo` that have a `bar_id` that does not have a corresponding entry in `bar`.

There is an index on `foo.bar_id` and a unique (incremental) index on `bar.id`

The output of explain looks like this:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  foo NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4411867 100.00  NULL
1   SIMPLE  bar NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   foo.bar_id  1   100.00  Using where; Not exists
```

(sorry, i've struggled to get the formatting of that table to display very nicely).

This query is sometimes taking 5+ minutes (although for some reason it sometimes takes 30 seconds shortly after running for 5 minutes)

Is there anyway to improve it? Or is it just a hardware limitation?

---

In response to the comments, this version makes no noticeable improvement in terms of performance.

```sql
        SELECT foo.* FROM foo
        LEFT JOIN bar
        ON bar.id = foo.bar_id
        WHERE bar.id IS NULL
        ORDER BY foo.id ASC
        LIMIT 30;
```

There is a slight difference when selecting `foo.*` as opposed to `*` but in my case I was selecting specific columns anyway, I just did not think to include them in the pseudo example.

Comment: Limiting without ordering rarely makes sense.

Comment: Step 1. Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: The spurious results that take 30 seconds may be due to caching. Don't rely on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

The query *as written* must check `foo` rows until it finds 30 missing rows from `bar`.  If `foo` is big, and there aren't many missing rows, that could take a long time.

**Maybe**

You have `SELECT *`.  See if it runs faster if it returns only `SELECT foo.id`.  There is no need for the `bar.*` part of `*`; they will always be `NULL`.  If `id` is not sufficient, you can use `id` to get other columns.

**Yes**

If you are walking through the table picking a few (30) to work on and delete, this is a terribly inefficient way to do it.  It is "Order(N^2)".  I have a *much* faster way (O(N)), which involves "remembering where you left off":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks  (That discussion is couched in terms of "deleting in chunks", but it can be adapted to other actions.)

Comment: Of course 'walking through' implies an order, which is absent here

Comment: In my real world case a human has to be able to read each row first via an admin UI (not direct MySQL access). If it was a simple case of trying to bulk delete I agree there may be better solutions. To be clear, the real world case is returning a list in a table and deleting each one manually after inspection.

Comment: @JohnMellor - My technique can either be used to get, but not delete, 30 rows at a time.  Or the technique of continuing after the last one could let you very efficiently get rows one at a time.  `WHERE id > $left_off ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` .  Using the `PRIMARY KEY` may be the most efficient; but you might want to use a datetime column (that is indexed) to walk through them in chronological order.

Comment: And...  Your current method gets slower and slower.  This because it scans more and more of the table to find the "next" 30.  Continuing where "you left off" avoids that.

Comment: @Strawberry - Using an "order" leads to a much faster algorithm.  If the OP deliberately wanted something like `ORDER BY RAND()`, then it is trickier.  Some possible tricks:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random